# How to make InMemory.db a Memory mapped file and use it as database in MFC

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite

I have to use InMemory.db in my project but the performance is slow the InMemory.db size is 10 MB. Some queries which retrives more than 30000 records take a lot of time. Is their any way I can improve the performance?

How to make InMemory.db a memory mapped file and use it as database in MFC. An example will be very helpful.

Thanks Space_C0wb0y

The reason for creating the .db file is to distribute the file to differnt users.

I want to load this (InMemory.db) file in memory and use that file or is their any way to create the in-memory database using the .db file.

The queries are like

```
Select 
    ltoken, date_mm, Vcontract_name, price, quantity, 
    field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, 
    field8, field9, field10, field11, field12....., fieldn 
from contract
```

Thanks Steve Townsend

The problem is this .db file is provided by the client I am supposed to use it so can not change the schema or any thing in the database

I can only do the programming to use this file directly by opening connection to the file.

I dont know how to loading this file in memory

I did some google on it and found that their is some way i can load this file in memory and use it as a database

But I wasn't successful so can someone help me out for loading this file in memory any example will be helpful

Comment: Is there a special reason for you writing *InMemory.db* instead of *in-memory database*?

Comment: This also depends heavily on the database-schema and the queries. Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

This size of DB should be fully cacheable on any Windows desktop without you doing any extra work.

Check your SQL and your schema (esp. table indices) before the DB.